# Unity3d animated cursor

Tags: unity-game-engine

For change cursor I using this:

```
UnityEngine.Cursor.SetCursor(
        CursorTexture, 
        new Vector2(CursorTexture.width, CursorTexture.height) * 0.5f,
        CursorMode.ForceSoftware);
```

I want to animate cursor when something happens.

Is it possible to animate cursor using `Cursor.SetCursor`?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? Just change the cursor in set intervals, you already have the code to do so.

Comment: I create 18 images(rotate on 10 degrees). I tried using this method, but when I run game in browser cursor does not rotated but in editor It works. 

public IEnumerator AnimateCursor()
{
  while(true)
  {
     if (this.IsAnimatable(this.Cursor))
     {
        cursorIndex++;
        var t = GetTexture(this.Cursor, this.cursorIndex);
    if (t == null)
    {
     cursorIndex = 0;
     t = GetTexture(this.Cursor, this.cursorIndex);
    }
     this.SetCursorTexture(t);
    }

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
   }
 }

Comment: And maybe exists other methed where I can use one image(istead of many images).

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like LearnCocos2D says.  The problem will be it will flicker a lot and the other problem you will most likely have is that the mouse pointer will be really sluggish.  This is because software mouse pointers are not rendered by hardware so its always a couple of frames behind actual user's input on the pointer device.

Then for the animated texture to work on web browser you need to make sure you export the needed shaders you are using if anything on a resources folder of your web player project since lots of shaders are not exported to the web build by default.  It should work if you are using a standard diffuse, but I think that for a mouse pointer since most likely it uses transparency then it may not work by default. You'll need to find the actual shader being used and export that by manually for your build.

Unity should have support for hardware animated cursors at least on PC, but sadly it doesn't...